# Change the URL hash value with the reached div id

Tags: jquery, css

Consider the following snippet:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1" class="flag"></div> 
    /* some text */

    <div id="2"  class="flag"></div> 
    /* some text */

    <div id="3"  class="flag"></div> 
    /* some text */
</div>
```

The container is overflow, it has a scroll bar. I need to change the hash value in the URL with the id of the div reached while scrolling.
For example, the scroll bar is in the top/bottom of the container. I start scrolling down/up, once I reach a div, I change the hash value of the URL to the *id of this reached div*.

This way changes the hash value to a very specific value when I reach a very specific div(JQuery):

```
                var t = $("#someDiv").offset().top;
                $("#container").scroll(function(){
                    if($(this).scrollTop() > t )
                    {   
                        location.hash = "100";
                    }
                });
```

What to change to make it work as needed? Any snippets, keywords or links will be appreciated.

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, so I'll just post it as a comment: In CSS, `id` values cannot start with a digit (they can't in HTML4 and earlier, either; HTML5 opens things up). Since jQuery uses CSS selectors, and defers them to the browser's own selector engine when it can, and an `id` selector starting with a digit (e.g., `#1`) is invalid, I'd avoid using `id` values starting with digits.

Comment: Thanks Crowder. Actually it worked with a digit normally. This isn't my problem. The problem is that I don't know the reached div to change the hash value accordingly.

Comment: Just because it works, it doesn't mean it's valid. Good developers follow the spec :)

Comment: It's OK Christian. I understand =) .

Comment: @Nadj: FWIW, I recall seeing it fail on some browsers. I don't immediately recall whether it failed on its own or only if part of a larger selector (e.g., `#1 div span`), which jQuery will farm out. (jQuery handles `#1` using `getElementById`, unless it hits the IE bug with getElementById, in which case it resorts to a selector query).

Comment: Thanks Crowsder, I'll take your advice in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check every `div`?

```
$("#container").scroll(function() {
    $('#container > div').each(function() {
        if( $("#container").offset().top > $(this).offset().top ) {
            window.location.hash = this.id;
        }
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZjWP/

Comment: Well Christian, it worked with the first div. It's weird that the browser is stack on the first div, I can't continue to scroll to next divs, what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the code didn't work as I intended. Also had an extra bracket. I've updated it with a jsFiddle demonstration.

Comment: Your code works in jsfiddle, but what is not working is: `location.hash = this.id;`. It worked on the first div, but after changing the hash to the id of that div, the browser stops to scroll.

Comment: The problem is in the > operation, there are many many `if` tests happen as firebug show. Are there any other way to do it?

Comment: That's because there's no such thing as `location.hash`. It's `window.location.hash`. I just copied your code, thinking you'd done it for a reason. Secondly, the scroll event fires on, well, scroll. Which is _quite often_ so to speak. You could reverse the array and limit the checking of all divs, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZjWP/1/. Chances are you still won't be happy with that, even though it wouldn't slow down the slowest of machines, so you could also do it on an interval, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZjWP/3/. Of course that fires when you're not scrolling though. That's all I've got.

Comment: Thanks Christia. `location.hash` worked, but it may be less respectful to the spec. The way you set interval really changes the hash value but the browser still acts strangely; when I click on the scroll bar and scroll it up an and down, the hash changes but when I release it, it returns to the top of the container. I'll see what to do, but if you have a quick fix, thanks for posting it.